# How to swipe in appium real device my swipe is Deprecated

Tags: java, android, appium-android

```
                      How to swipe in appium real device my swipe is 
               Deprecated 

            in the latest android studio 2.3.3
            i am using java client 5.00 BETA 6 in eclipse 
            appium server desktop 1.7

          i tried the following method none works 
         following code does not not swipe the page down 

          i am trying to swipe in device setting  to click down page which is 
       not visible in view

        1.  new TouchAction(driver)
         .longPress(393, 446)
          .moveTo(1902, 407)
          .release()
           .perform();

       2. driver.swipe(startx, starty, endx, endy, duration);  its depreceted

       3. 
       MobileElement element = (MobileElement) 



       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@resource-
          id,'title') and @text='Display']"));
       JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
           HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
        scrollObject.put("direction", "down"); 
              scrollObject.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId());
             scrollObject.put("text", "Memory"); 
           js.executeScript("mobile: scrollTo", scrollObject);

             please help me to overcome from this i in deed stuck with this last 
             2 weeks please help me to overcome from this 


    Also please help me to swipe from left to 
    bottom as i need to know about 
    swipe in details i in deed stuck in
 appium swipe please help me come out out of this i tried lot of method
```

mostly it wont works
please help me
Also please help me to swipe from left to 
        bottom as i need to know about 
        swipe in details i in deed stuck in
    How to swipe in appium real device my swipe is 
               Deprecated 
         Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a wait for that TouchAction?

You have:

```
new TouchAction(driver)
                .longPress(393, 446)
                .moveTo(1902, 407)
                .release()
                .perform();
```

Try this (change longPress for just press):

```
//Coordinates are relative, So at .moveTo(x,y) you have to add how many X and Y 
  do you want to moveTo from the start where you pressed...


new TouchAction(driver)
                .press(393, 446)
                .wait(500)
                .moveTo(400, 0) //This will move 400px from start point (393) 
                .release()
                .perform();
```

*Note*: You have your screen size as limit for moveTo (also for .press, click...) If your screenWidth is 800 and you .press(400, anyY), at moveTo you can only add .moveTo(400...

And with driver swipe (**which is deprecated**...)

```
//startX, startY, endX, endY and 1tap
driver.swipe(393, 446, 1902, 407, 1)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for replay         when i execute the above code i got error                                                                     
 new TouchAction(driver)
  .press(393, 446)
  .wait(500);
  .moveTo(400, 0)
  .release()
  .perform();    When i execute above code it shows error in  .moveTo(400, 0)  The method moveTo(int, int) is undefined for the type basic   please help me come out of it   this error is show only when i add wait method in between the code

Comment: And also i need to move an element to the exact location using element id please help me to come out of it

Comment: Are you working with native app or is a mobile web app? Think you will see the whole page with mobile web apps, even if they are outside your screen... So the way to find the element is different between both

Comment: Hi i am working on native app but any way even in mobile web app i don't see whole page that are outside my screen.  can you please help me to swipe in native app  thanks in advance